# Can't get mule IMAP working

Tags: mule, imap

I've got the following flow but it doesn't work:

```
<flow name="flows1Flow1" >
    <imap:inbound-endpoint host="mail.example.com" port="143" user="helpdesk%40example.com" password="password" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="IMAP"/>
```

I've got error message:

Line 13 in XML document from URL [file
:/C:Path/workspace/.mule/apps/imap-test/imap-test.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sa
x.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'imap:inbound-endpoint'.

With such a simple flow, what can go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include the namespace at the root element:

```
xmlns:imap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap"
xsi:schemaLocation="... http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/imap/current/mule-imap.xsd">
```

And you should make sure you are actually depending on `mule-transport-email`.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Now I'm up and running! /Claes